# Finding List Index of Values in Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe how do I create a new column called "MemWeight" containing the index position in "mem_list" of each value in the Weighting column?

```
data = {'MemRef': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 'MemName': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 'Weighting': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.97, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

mem_list = [1.96, 1.97, 1.98, 1.99, 2]
```

The following does not work and returns the error below:

```
df["MemWeight"] = mem_list.index(df["Weighting"])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Documents/PycharmProjects/test.py", line 270, in <module>
    df["MemWeight"] = mem_list.index(df["Weighting"])
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1538, in __nonzero__
    f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

None of the suggestions in the error work. They give a miriad of other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), a dictionary comprehension, and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['MemWeight'] = df['Weighting'].map({k: v for v,k in enumerate(mem_list)})
```

Or [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (creating a new DataFrame):

```
out = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'Weighting': mem_list,
                             'MemWeight': range(len(mem_list)),
                            }), how='left')
```

*Note that you could also use `df['MemWeight'] = df['Weighting'].apply(mem_list.index)` but that would be inefficient (searching again the list for all rows).*

Output:

```
    MemRef MemName  Weighting  MemWeight
0        1       a       2.00          4
1        2       a       2.00          4
2        3       a       2.00          4
3        4       a       2.00          4
4        5       a       2.00          4
5        6       a       2.00          4
6        7       a       2.00          4
7        8       a       2.00          4
8        9       a       2.00          4
9       10       a       2.00          4
10      11       a       2.00          4
11      12       a       1.97          1
12      13       a       2.00          4
13      14       a       2.00          4
14      15       a       2.00          4
15      16       a       2.00          4
16      17       a       2.00          4
17      18       a       2.00          4
18      19       a       2.00          4
19      20       a       2.00          4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) since your `mem_list` is sorted:

```
df['MemWeight'] = pd.cut(df['Weighting'], bins=[-np.inf, *mem_list, np.inf], labels=False)
print(df)

# Output
    MemRef MemName  Weighting  MemWeight
0        1       a       2.00          4
1        2       a       2.00          4
2        3       a       2.00          4
3        4       a       2.00          4
4        5       a       2.00          4
5        6       a       2.00          4
6        7       a       2.00          4
7        8       a       2.00          4
8        9       a       2.00          4
9       10       a       2.00          4
10      11       a       2.00          4
11      12       a       1.97          1
12      13       a       2.00          4
13      14       a       2.00          4
14      15       a       2.00          4
15      16       a       2.00          4
16      17       a       2.00          4
17      18       a       2.00          4
18      19       a       2.00          4
19      20       a       2.00          4
```

Or with [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
df['MemWeight'] = np.searchsorted(mem_list, df['Weighting'], side='left')
```

Comment: Take care when you deal with real numbers (floating number precision) especially with the other solution :-)